# Filter articles by category

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, symphony-cms

I am trying to show articles from specific categories on my homepage.

xml removed.

**Note:** The category I need to fetch from is id=38. Which is showing but possibly by chance as it is included in the current articles.

I have fixed this problem, using a [solution I found here](http://www.getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/103178/).
It was simple enough. My datasource was filtering categories as {$ds-categories}. I changed that to just 38 and it worked perfectly. Knew it would be something simple.

There's my home page doing this, which outputs blank divs in place of what should show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:import href="../utilities/master.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="../utilities/get-article.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="../utilities/pagination.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="../utilities/get-notes.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="../utilities/get-comments.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="data">
<div id="content" class="container">
        <div id="content">
          <div class="col content">
            <div class="col span1">
              <h4 class="n4">Recent entries</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="homepage-articles/entry" mode="short"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="homepage-updates/entry" mode="updates"/>
                  </div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="col last">
            <xsl:call-template name="contact"/>
              <xsl:call-template name="social"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="category"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="tag"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="external-links"/>
        </div>
            </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then my get-article template looks something like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="entry" mode="updates">
<div>
  <xsl:for-each select="entry[@handle = updates]">
            <div class="post-meta">
              <span><xsl:call-template name="format-date">
                    <xsl:with-param name="date" select="date"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="format" select="'D M'"/>
                </xsl:call-template></span>
              <span id="year"><xsl:call-template name="format-date">
                <xsl:with-param name="date" select="date"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="format" select="'Y'"/>
              </xsl:call-template></span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <xsl:text>Tagged as: </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="tags/item">
                            <a href="{$root}/archive/tag/{@handle}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
                            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="{$root}/post/{title/@handle}#comments"><xsl:value-of select="@comments"/> comment<xsl:if test="@comments != 1">s</xsl:if></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="post-content last span-7">
                <h3><a href="{$root}/post/{title/@handle}"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a></h3>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="body/*[position() &lt; 3]" mode="html"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="get-images" />
              <p style="float: right; clear: both;"><a href="{$root}/post/{title/@handle}" title="Read {title}">Read the full article</a></p>
            </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

Thanks for the help! It definitely help me avoid bumping into further problems once I did solve this.

Comment: Can you please provide the original XML, the XSLT you've been working with, and an example of the expected result?

Comment: @NickG I have updated the main comment to show all relevant info. I feel it may be a problem with my datasource which is currently fetching from articles section like the homepage-articles. I can provide a screenshot of this setup if that will help.

Comment: To check your data source and the entries it contains, add `?debug` to the end of the URL when logged in to Symphony CMS.

Comment: @DavidOliver yes as far as I can tell my datasource is working like homepage articles and fetching all articles. When really all I want is an in-page category view a bit like an archive page. The fact no articles are showing up on the page (but are in the xml) tells me something is wrong in my xslt. I'll keep fiddling and if I figure it out post what was happening.

Comment: @DavidOliver Thanks! I have solved this after a few hours googling. Everything was fine just my bad datasource filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first template, you have an **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="homepage-updates/entry" mode="updates"/>
```

You also has the template that matches this

```
<xsl:template match="entry" mode="updates">
```

So far, so good. But within this "entry" template, you then do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry[@handle = updates]">
```

This is looking for an **entry** element that is a child of the current **entry** element you are matching, or which there are none in your XML.

Try changing the template match to match the parent element instead:

```
<xsl:template match="homepage-updates" mode="updates">
```

And then change the **xsl:apply-templates** accordingly

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="homepage-updates" mode="updates"/>
```

Comment: Ok. That didn't seem to work. It just removed the blank divs I had... Would altering my template and putting the for-each statement in the page work here?

Comment: Hmmm... It's hard to give a precise answer without seeing a complete version of the XML or XSLT (at the moment, for example, you XSLT is looking for an attribute called **handle** on the **entry** element, but not such attribute exists). Ideally, you could try reducing your XML and XSLT to the absolute bare minimum that reproduces the problem, and then show that in your question. You might find stripping this away helps you identify the actual problem yourself. Thanks!

Comment: alright! I fixed it. All I had to do was change my datasource. I had categories outputting the whole selection. Just changed it to 38, the id of update category. Also got rid of the for-each stuff and it works perfectly! Thanks for your help.